# Download button for Featured Image in every post - automatically

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I want to add download button for featured image in every post automatically in WordPress with the usage of php files. I don't want to use shortcodes, custom html in every post or plugins, cause I need automated, simple and reliable solution.

This is my code showing featured image in the single post content page.

```
<div <?php post_class( 'inside item' ); ?>>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-page', array( 'class' => 'featured-image' ) ); ?></a>
```

Underneath I would like to add a button to download this particular image:

```
<a class="download_image" href="<?php featured-image-link?; ?>"
>Download this Image</a>
```

But I don't know how to provide an automatic link to the photo in its full size (which can be seen above).

Thanks for all your suggestions and comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `the_post_thumbnail_url();` to get the thumbnail URL. 
More infos about the function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

```
<a class="download_image" href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>">Download this Image</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to play with it a little bit! Will be back soon.

Comment: Okay, It works for me just fine. I just add some code for it to force the download, not open in the browser. I'll drop it here for others: "<a class="download_image" href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>" download>Download this Image</a>". Thank you once again!